# Should the bigger "view" monitor smaller "tiles," or should tiles check if they are themselves in view?

Tags: class, object

I'm developing a simple ASCII, grid-based, top-down game in JavaScript (but answers in other languages are fine). At the moment, conceptually, there is a `Map` class for the entire explorable area, a `View` class for what is currently onscreen, and a `Tile` class for each text character that can appear on the grid.

As the user moves their own character, the view shifts to show a different cropped section of the map. The program needs to know whether tiles that can move, like NPCs, are in the view at any given moment, and this is where I struggle with a decision:

- As there is only ever one view for the lifecycle of the app, should each `Tile` be given a reference to that object when instantiated, and have an `isInView` method it can use itself to check if true?
- Or, should the one view be global/singleton/similar, and referenced inside `someTile.isInView()`?
- Or, should the view be passed to that function each time it's called, i.e. `someTile.isInView(theView)`?
- Or, should only the view have a function, with each tile passed to it to check, i.e. `theView.canSee(someTile)`?
- Or...?

My assumption is that, based on avoiding memory issues etc., and not referencing things "backwards," one approach is (reasonably) objectively better than others, even if they all technically work.

Thank you.